# SUGAR CRM 7 install with MS SQL

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, vagrant, virtual-machine, sugarcrm

I'm creating a VM image that can be shared in the office where Sugar CRM 7 can be run with MS SQL. I've experienced many problems but have reached what seems like the final hurdle where I am running the Sugar install.php file to connect to DB and I get a Database Error. Sugarcrm log states:

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Could not create constraint. 
Error creating indexes Query Failed:ALTER TABLE kreportsnapshotsdata ADD CONSTRAINT snapshot_data PRIMARY KEY (snapshot_id,record_id)::: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'kreportsnapshotsdata'.

I can see I have connectivity to Database Engine as it does create the new DB which is visible in MS SQL Express, but it's not complete (missing indexes)

My set up is 
- Windows Server 2008 VM
- XAMPP with PHP 5.5
- MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Since, the error logs refer to ODBC Driver 11
I also installed the following MS drivers
  Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server 
      https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098
  Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server® - Windows
      https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

Any ideas of where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error, there might be a bug in Kreports while using MS SQL. Are any of the columns snapshot_id or record_id in the table kreportsnapshotsdata nullable? If so, try removing nullable and see if it makes a difference